# How to make Apple Assessment Mode work on Mac app built with Electron?

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder, entitlements

- **Electron-Builder Version**: 22.8.1
- **Node Version**: 12.16.3
- **Electron Version**: 10.1.3
- **Electron-Updater Version**: 4.3.5
- **Target**: mac, dmg

Hi! I need to be able to run my Mac app in Assessment Mode. But even though I use a provisioning profile with the Assessment Mode capability enabled, the moment I add the `com.apple.developer.automatic-assessment-configuration` entitlement to my entitlements.mac.plist file, the app cannot be launched anymore and I get this error:

> The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10826 "kLSNoLaunchPermissionErr:
> User doesn't have permission to launch the app (managed networks)"
> UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard, _LSLine=2508,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x137622890 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain
> Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch
> failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x13761c7d0 {Error
> Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed with error:
> 153}}}}}

[image: Permission erorr popup]

I was able to reproduce the issue even using the boilerplate from https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

The steps I done are:

1. added these entitlements to my entitlements.mac.plist file (as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_automatic-assessment-configuration?language=objc)):

   ```
   <key>com.apple.developer.automatic-assessment-configuration</key>
   <true/>
   <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
   <array>
       <string>com.apple.assessmentagent</string>
   </array>
   ```
2. enabled the following Additional Capabilities for my app ID in Identifiers at developer.apple.com

- Automatic Assessment Configuration

3. enabled the following Entitlements for my Developer ID Application Provisioning Profile linked to my app ID and Developer ID Application certificate at developer.apple.com

- macOS Automatic Assessment Configuration (Developer ID)

After building the app, I cannot start it and get the errors mentioned above. Removing the `com.apple.developer.automatic-assessment-configuration` entitlement, makes the app launch as normal. I've been trying to solve this for a while now, but nothing has worked so far. Could you please help me figure out what might be the issue here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The entitlement has been updated to:

> com.apple.developer.edu-assessment-mode