# Electron app does not work on Mac Assessment Mode

Tags: electron

I encountered an issue with an Electron app when enabling Mac Assessment Mode (verified through the assessmentSessionDidBegin function, and Mac Assessment Mode's working fine). But the application hangs on a gray screen, and I have to restart my Mac to exit the app. I suspect that the helper processes (render, GPU, etc.) of the Electron app are being blocked in Assessment Mode, causing the app to become unresponsive. Additionally, I have tried adding the calculator application to the whitelist, and it works fine. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue? Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you try [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138396/how-to-make-apple-assessment-mode-work-on-mac-app-built-with-electron)? It did not help you? if it is true, it is better to state that on text.

Comment: Yep, It didn't help me